# I'm an Indian married to a US citizen and live in the US. But my parents are not aware of this. How will this affect their visa application?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, weddings

Long story short, my parents are from a very traditional Hindu background and would be very hurt if they learned that I married someone from outside our caste, let alone an atheist foreigner. I thus decided to never tell them. They’re very old in their seventies and I just don’t want to them discover this fact and lose their tranquility in the last few years of their life. For the sake of this question, please assume this decision as given. I’m still in touch with my parents and we talk once or twice every month.

The problem is, they may want to visit the US. I wouldn’t have to invite them; they have the financial means to apply for a visitor’s visa and come here by themselves. In this case, they would have to provide information about their son which includes my marital status. They will be putting it as “single”, and I’m guessing the immigration officer will most likely catch the inconsistency and reject their application.

Do I need to worry about this?
If yes, will the officer let them know exactly why it was rejected, thus revealing my true marital status to them?

Comment: It seems to me that if your parents show up in the US you're going to have a much bigger problem concealing your marital status than just the visa form. It might be worth a question on [interpersonal.se] to see if someone can suggest a way to tell your parents about your spouse without upsetting them.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass As an Indian, I can understand his problem. You cannot even remotely compare it with US situation. He can only understand the family situation. Ultra orthodox with very strong caste system makes it a very difficult choice.

Comment: @anish I'm not comparing anything. If the OP's parents come banging on his door and asking to stay, is he going to hide his wife jn a motel for three months? I'm not trying to understate the scale of the problem, just suggesting that there might be a better way.

Comment: "I'm guessing the immigration officer will most likely catch the inconsistency and reject their application": not likely.  How would they find out?  Do you think they'd examine your income tax records or the civil register of the county that issued your marriage license?  Visa officers have better things to do, and I suspect they aren't actually authorized to receive that information because of privacy protections.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass  The OPs coverup is probably not compatible with his parents staying in his home and if they end up at his door he's probably screwed.  If his parents are the type to stick to premade plans that can be avoided by him joining them at a location away from home without his spouse.

Comment: Honestly, how are you planning on hiding the fact that you're married from them once they arrive in the US? Is your wife aware that you're planning on passing her off as a roommate or something?

Comment: Given your situation, wouldn't it be best for your parents not to travel to the US at all? You can do it the honest way by persuading them, or you could sabotage their visa application (possibly underhanded, but so is not telling them about your marriage). If the goal is for your parents to have a nice holiday, perhaps with you joining them, there are many other countries to choose from.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The [*DS-160: Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application*](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application.html) does not ask for your marital status.

It will ask the applicant if they have any immediate relatives in the US, for which they will answer Yes. It will then ask for your surname, given name, your relationship to the applicant (e.g. child), and your status in the US (US citizen, permanent resident, etc). These are the only questions on the visa form that will be about you.

Comment: What if OP's actual status in the US doesn't match what his parents think it is? I can imagine that if for example the application says he's on long-term non-immigrant visa while he actually became a LPR through marriage to a US citizen, that might raise some questions. OP, what's your status in the US?

Comment: @TooTea In that case, they might have a problem!

Comment: @TooTea It feels OP can just lie to them and tell them that they became a LPR in some other way? It's not like OP is on a "no white lies" basis, and I doubt that their senior Indian parents would be able to tell whether the story they tell them is plausible or not.

Comment: @xLeitix Sure, but perhaps it might be good to let the parents know beforehand (whatever the explanation) so that they put the right status into their applications. I'm just guessing, I don't know whether getting that field wrong could actually jeopardise the application (I've never had to apply for US visa myself).

Comment: @xLeitix or even reveal it by selectively disclosing facts without lying at all, e.g., "Yeah, I got some help a few years ago to switch over to LPR, oh by the way, how's your sister?"

Comment: I could not locate a PDF of the DS-160 but an example of the online form is here: https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/PDF-other/DS-160-Example_11012019.pdf That may be helpful to this answer to show what is on the DS-160. It is quite lengthy and I could not readily locate the relevant page though.

Comment: @TooTea it appears to me that if they put that field wrong and that jeopardizes their visa application it would be a win for the OP. I don't see why he needs to make special arrangements for their theoretical visa application if he'd rather avoid/not risk revealing his status.

Comment: I think this is the best response. It's absolutely critical that the parents submit correct information on their application, and they should generally know their son's current status in the US. So this can be communicated in some way even as the marriage is hidden. Yes, this definitely counts as weaving a more tangled web, but it's probably the way forward given the constraints.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Would it be possible for OP to file the visa application on his parents behalf?